# npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I was trying to create an app through ng new my-app and had this error several times.
How can I fix that?

```
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/browserslist: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-01-22T20_05_16_466Z-debug-0.log
✖ Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```